# .NET Date/Javascript/jQuery Date Converter

Tags: jquery, .net, datetime, datepicker, date-format

I am writing an application that needs to convert a .NET date format string (e.g. `dd/MM/yyyy`) to an equivalent javascript/jQuery date format, to feed the jQuery UI Date Picker plugin (e.g. `dd/mm/yy`).

Details of the plugin format can be found here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

My question is, are there any plugins/libraries/methods anyone knows of that do this already?

Otherwise I'll be writing my own server side method along these lines:

```
public static string GetJavascriptDateFormat(string dotNetFormatString) {
    var resultString = dotNetFormatString;
    resultString =  resultString.Replace("yyyy","yy");
    //etc
    return resultString;
}

public static string GetDotNetDateFormat(string javascriptDateFormatString) {

}
```

Comment: Why would js prefer /yy ??? Just feed it mm/dd/yyyy which is understood just fine

Comment: The datepicker plugin renders /yyyy as 20102010 as far as I can tell.  Maybe there aren't many differences, in which case my method above may almost encapsulate it.

Comment: Which date picker and how do you feed it?

Comment: Have edited the question to make it clearer (jQuery UI datepicker)

Comment: have you had a look at moment.js? [http://momentjs.com/]

Answer (score -1):

I usually avoid using JSON encoded dates.

JSON date encoding and decoding is horrible and difficult to debug.
The best is the pass dates as strings between .Net and javascript.
In other words, let your C# code format the date for you and send the formatted date as a string in JSON.

Comment: I know, and usually I would.  But I need to get the datePicker to work with the client date, so this doesn't help me.